# Cannot concatenate to array with ++

Tags: arrays, list, scala, random, generator

It seems that I can't add the value `specChrando` to the `A` value using `++`.

```
val alphabet1 = "qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"
val lowerCh = alphabet1.toCharArray
val higherCh = alphabet1.toUpperCase.toCharArray
val numb = "1234567890".toCharArray
val specialCh = "#@".toCharArray
val numRando = Random.shuffle(numb.toList).take(2)
val specChrando = Random.shuffle(specialCh.toList).head
val A = lowerCh ++ higherCh ++ numRando ++ specChrando
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` returns single element while `++` expects inputs to be collections. Try changing to use `take(1)` instead of `head`

Comment: Or change `++` to `:+`